# BehaviorSubject in Angular2 is not set value second time?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, angular2-directives

My code is like

**login.component.ts**

```
loginSucess () {
  this.MenuService.setUserName(userauthresponce.username);
 }
```

**MenuService.ts**

```
 private usernameSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);
  setUserName (username) {
    this.usernameSource.next(username);
 }

 getUserName () {
  return  this.usernameSource.asObservable();
    }
```

**other.component.ts**

```
constructor(MenuService:MenuService) {

  this.MenuService.getUserName().subscribe(responce => {
  console.log('username', responce);
  this.username = responce;
});
  }

/* it's not working hear*/

 switchrole() {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    this.MenuService.setUserName(this.username);
}
```

I am getting username when first login , after that when user clicks switch role button it's calling switch role function, In this function I have to navigate the page to dashboard, In that case I am getting username as 0;

Even I am set username from switchrole() , but this is not working

I am not getting my error please help me

Comment: Where are you providing `MenuService`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not calling `this.usernameSource.asObservable()` and just return `this.usernameSource` as you can subscribe to a `BehaviorSubject` directly but you can not call next on an Observable;

ex.

```
private usernameSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);

setUserName (username) {
  this.usernameSource.next(username);
}

getUserName () {
  return  this.usernameSource;
}
```